# AWS Data Pipeline CopyActivity Error: Parameter index out of range

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-rds

I'm setting up a data pipeline in AWS to load a CSV file from S3 into a MySQL RDS database. I used the template for this exact data flow to set up my pipeline, but the pipeline fails on the CopyActivity when trying to insert the data in to the table. The Error I get is `Parameter index out of range (43 > number of parameters, which is 42).` -- more detailed version below.

The CSV is generated using a Python script on my local machine (Mac OS 10.14) and is uploaded to S3 by the same script. I've made sure that `linedelimeter="\n"`, `csv.QUOTE_NONE`, and `escapechar="\\"` have been set when writing the CSV in my Python script.

Here's the pipeline:

```
  "objects": [
    {
      "output": {
        "ref": "DestinationRDSTable"
      },
      "input": {
        "ref": "S3InputDataLocation"
      },
      "dependsOn": {
        "ref": "RdsMySqlTableCreateActivity"
      },
      "name": "DataLoadActivity",
      "id": "DataLoadActivity",
      "runsOn": {
        "ref": "Ec2Instance"
      },
      "type": "CopyActivity"
    },
    {
      "*password": "#{*myRDSPassword}",
      "name": "rds_mysql",
      "jdbcProperties": "allowMultiQueries=true",
      "id": "rds_mysql",
      "type": "RdsDatabase",
      "rdsInstanceId": "#{myRDSInstanceId}",
      "username": "#{myRDSUsername}"
    },
    {
      "instanceType": "t1.micro",
      "name": "Ec2Instance",
      "actionOnTaskFailure": "terminate",
      "securityGroups": "#{myEc2RdsSecurityGrps}",
      "id": "Ec2Instance",
      "type": "Ec2Resource",
      "terminateAfter": "2 Hours"
    },
    {
      "database": {
        "ref": "rds_mysql"
      },
      "name": "RdsMySqlTableCreateActivity",
      "runsOn": {
        "ref": "Ec2Instance"
      },
      "id": "RdsMySqlTableCreateActivity",
      "type": "SqlActivity",
      "script": "#{myRDSCreateTableSql}"
    },
    {
      "failureAndRerunMode": "CASCADE",
      "resourceRole": "DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole",
      "role": "DataPipelineDefaultRole",
      "pipelineLogUri": "s3://envoy-pipeline-logs/",
      "scheduleType": "ONDEMAND",
      "name": "Default",
      "id": "Default"
    },
    {
      "name": "DataFormat1",
      "id": "DataFormat1",
      "type": "CSV"
    },
    {
      "database": {
        "ref": "rds_mysql"
      },
      "name": "DestinationRDSTable",
      "insertQuery": "#{myRDSTableInsertSql}",
      "id": "DestinationRDSTable",
      "type": "SqlDataNode",
      "table": "#{myRDSTableName}",
      "selectQuery": "select * from #{table}"
    },
    {
      "directoryPath": "#{myInputS3Loc}",
      "dataFormat": {
        "ref": "DataFormat1"
      },
      "name": "S3InputDataLocation",
      "id": "S3InputDataLocation",
      "type": "S3DataNode"
    }
  ],
  "parameters": [
    {
      "description": "RDS MySQL password",
      "id": "*myRDSPassword",
      "type": "String"
    },
    {
      "watermark": "security group name",
      "helpText": "The names of one or more EC2 security groups that have access to the RDS MySQL cluster.",
      "description": "RDS MySQL security group(s)",
      "isArray": "true",
      "optional": "true",
      "id": "myEc2RdsSecurityGrps",
      "type": "String"
    },
    {
      "description": "RDS MySQL username",
      "id": "myRDSUsername",
      "type": "String"
    },
    {
      "description": "Input S3 file path",
      "id": "myInputS3Loc",
      "type": "AWS::S3::ObjectKey"
    },
    {
      "helpText": "The SQL statement to insert data into the RDS MySQL table.",
      "watermark": "INSERT INTO #{table} (col1, col2, col3) VALUES(?, ?, ?) ;",
      "description": "Insert SQL query",
      "id": "myRDSTableInsertSql",
      "type": "String"
    },
    {
      "helpText": "The name of an existing table or a new table that will be created based on the create table SQL query parameter below.",
      "description": "RDS MySQL table name",
      "id": "myRDSTableName",
      "type": "String"
    },
    {
      "watermark": "CREATE TABLE pet IF NOT EXISTS (name VARCHAR(20), owner VARCHAR(20), species VARCHAR(20), gender CHAR(1), birth DATE, death DATE);",
      "helpText": "The idempotent SQL statement to create the RDS MySQL table if it does not already exist.",
      "description": "Create table SQL query",
      "optional": "true",
      "id": "myRDSCreateTableSql",
      "type": "String"
    },
    {
      "watermark": "DB Instance",
      "description": "RDS Instance ID",
      "id": "myRDSInstanceId",
      "type": "String"
    }
  ],
  "values": {
    "myRDSInstanceId": "{rds_instance}",
    "myRDSUsername": "master",
    "myRDSTableInsertSql": "INSERT INTO #{table}(transaction_id,subscription_id,transaction_type,transaction_status,escrow_status,created_at,merchant_account,currency_iso_code,service_fee,tax_amount,tax_exempt,purchase_order_number,order_id,refund_transaction_id,payment_instrument_type,credit_card_type,cardholder_name,last_four_of_credit_card,expiration_date,credit_card_customer_location,payment_method_token,credit_card_unique_identifier,processor_response_code,processor_response_text,gateway_rejection_reason,avs_postal_code_response_code,avs_street_address_response_code,cvv_response_code,country_of_issuance,issuing_bank,durbin_regulated,commercial,prepaid,payroll,healthcare,debit,type,transaction_source,amount_authorized,settlement_amount,settlement_date,amount_submitted_for_settlement) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);",
    "*myRDSPassword": "{pwd}",
    "myEc2RdsSecurityGrps": "{sec_grp}",
    "myRDSCreateTableSql": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS braintree (transaction_id VARCHAR(255),subscription_id VARCHAR(255),transaction_type VARCHAR(255),transaction_status VARCHAR(255),escrow_status VARCHAR(255),created_at datetime,merchant_account VARCHAR(255),currency_iso_code VARCHAR(255),service_fee float,tax_amount float,tax_exempt bit,purchase_order_number bigint,order_id bigint,refund_transaction_id VARCHAR(255),payment_instrument_type VARCHAR(255),credit_card_type VARCHAR(255),cardholder_name VARCHAR(255),last_four_of_credit_card int,expiration_date date,credit_card_customer_location VARCHAR(255),payment_method_token VARCHAR(255),credit_card_unique_identifier VARCHAR(255),processor_response_code VARCHAR(255),processor_response_text VARCHAR(255),gateway_rejection_reason VARCHAR(255),avs_postal_code_response_code VARCHAR(255),avs_street_address_response_code VARCHAR(255),cvv_response_code VARCHAR(255),country_of_issuance VARCHAR(255),issuing_bank VARCHAR(255),durbin_regulated VARCHAR(255),commercial VARCHAR(255),prepaid VARCHAR(255),payroll VARCHAR(255),healthcare VARCHAR(255),debit VARCHAR(255),type VARCHAR(255),transaction_source VARCHAR(255),amount_authorized float,settlement_amount float,settlement_date datetime,amount_submitted_for_settlement float,PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id));",
    "myInputS3Loc": "{s3_loc}",
    "myRDSTableName": "{table_name}"
  }
}
```

I would expect this to run to completion (which it does if I pass an empty CSV file to the pipeline), but instead I get the parameter index error mentioned above.

The error stack trace:

> amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskExecutionException: Error
>   copying record at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.copy.SingleThreadedCopyActivity.processAll(SingleThreadedCopyActivity.java:65)
>   at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.copy.SingleThreadedCopyActivity.runActivity(SingleThreadedCopyActivity.java:35)
>   at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.CopyActivity.runActivity(CopyActivity.java:22)
>   at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.objects.AbstractActivity.run(AbstractActivity.java:16)
>   at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeRemoteRunner(TaskPoller.java:136)
>   at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeTask(TaskPoller.java:105)
>   at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller$1.run(TaskPoller.java:81)
>   at
>   private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.executeWork(PollWorker.java:76)
>   at
>   private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.run(PollWorker.java:53)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out
>   of range (43 > number of parameters, which is 42). at
>   private.com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Unknown Source) at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlOutputConnector.addRecord(SqlOutputConnector.java:93)
>   at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlOutputConnector.writeRecord(SqlOutputConnector.java:65)
>   at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.copy.SingleThreadedCopyActivity.processAll(SingleThreadedCopyActivity.java:53)
>   ... 9 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of
>   range (43 > number of parameters, which is 42). at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3391)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3376)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4102)
>   at
>   amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlOutputConnector.addRecord(SqlOutputConnector.java:78)
>   ... 11 more